# centos 7 Mysql 5.6.3 change data directory error

Tags: mysql

I try to change Mysql 5.6 data directory in centos 7 from default dir `/var/lib/mysql` to target dir `/data1/mysqldata/mysql`.

Follow is my operation step by step

1.Stop mysql service

2.Create target directory and chown

```
mkdir /data1/mysqldata
chown -R mysql:mysql /data1/mysqldata
```

2.Change `/etc/my.cfg` to below code

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/data1/mysqldata/mysql
socket=/data1/mysqldata/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[client]
port=3306
socket=/data1/mysqldata/mysql/mysql.sock
```

4.Move data from default directory to target

```
mv /var/lib/mysql /data1/mysqldata/
```

5.Start mysql service

#### But I get error from /var/log/mysqld.log like this

```
190813 10:40:23 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
190813 10:40:23 mysqld_safe Directory '/data1/mysqldata/mysql' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

#### It's strange that Mysql run normaly in the default directory `/var/lib/mysql` when I undo all my config

My machine version is `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`, and Mysql Version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.45, for Linux (x86_64)`

Comment: Have you checked that the permission match?

Comment: How can I check this permission, I used root user to do this. And I have give directory permission to mysql user with ```chown``` command

Comment: You can check it using `ls` or `stat`. But besides: does the directory listed in the error message exist?

Comment: when I input ```stat ./mysqldata/``` command.
 I get this info 
```File: ‘mysqldata/’

  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory

Device: 811h/2065d Inode: 99614721    Links: 3

Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (   27/   mysql)   Gid: (   27/   mysql)

Access: 2019-08-15 16:34:35.403094339 +0800
Modify: 2019-07-24 14:02:57.452067339 +0800
Change: 2019-08-12 15:08:14.234390490 +0800

 Birth: -```

Comment: what about `mkdir -p /data1/mysqldata/mysql`?

Comment: Thanks ```mkdir -p /data1/mysqldata/mysql``` do not work for me. I think if it is the reason of permission wrong for root user or system. Because when I run command ```mysqld_safe```, and I get the permission error like ```[ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
2019-08-12 20:07:53 9544 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /data1/mysqldata/mysql/mysql.sock ?``` But I do not know how to check about this

Comment: After this error info, there are no ```mysql.sock``` file has been created in the target  folder ```/data1/mysqldata/mysql```, I guess if some software has change my root permission or not